# User profile cannot be loaded

Tags: windows-7, login

I play this online game called sudden attack which requires download, but recently its been loading slow. So I log off went into safe mode to try to figure out problem.

Once I couldn't figure it out I said forget it and tried to log back into normal mode, but once I tried to click on an account it kept saying **user profile cannot be loaded**. Please help me. I can only use safe mode to load an user account now. By the way I'm in safe mode so if anyone has any answers on how to access from safe mode... (Windows 7 Home Basic)

Answer (score 1):

You can try one of these solutions provided on the Microsoft Support page:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947215

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you some how managed to corrupt your user profile.

There are many ways to fix this, but, the quickest way (IMHO) is to create 2 new users, one that you want to keep and one to do the work from.

Log on as the one you want to keep, then log out.

Log on as the one you created to do the work from.

Navigate to `c:\users\<old name here>` (where old name is the name of the corrupt profile)... Make sure that you have hidden/system files visible, then get everything other than any file with `Ntuser` (with any extension) in the name, and copy this to the new user you created previously.

Now, log out with this user and log in with the user you want to keep. Whilst you may loose a few things (and could be very bad if using EFS), the majority of applications and settings should be retained.

There are more in depth steps we can try such as registry editing, but, this is by far the easiest approach.